# Automate Google Sheets Data Extraction and Email Notification

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

[LINK TO GOOGLE DOCS FOR THE CODE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R1jxeyeIz2D-x6qCi8wcJuiiq2XkRAdoJsrU7LQha8M/edit)

Error:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.'})  I
I have tied creating key creating a new spreadsheet changed the name nothing seems to work